# Different XSD for Create vs Update operations

Tags: xsd, soa

consider the following object:

```
<Person>
  <Name/>
  <FirstName/>
  <Street/>
  <City/>
  <SocialSecurityNr/>
  <Gender/>
  <Hobby/>
</Person>
```

Asume I use this object for a Create web service operation. When calling the Create operation, all fields of the Person object must  be provided except 'hobby'
Now assume that I also have an Update operation. When updating, only socialsecuritynumber is mandatory: I do not need to update each field.

How do you process this in an XSD? Should you define seperate XSDs for the create and update operation?

The reason I want to make this distinction is that I do not want to send unnecessary fields from sender to recipient when it is not needed. Hence, I want to use minOccurs = 0 as much as possible.

It feels like this is a common problem, but can't find any references about it

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you. I've seen both approaches.

If I want a comprehensive description of the service contract, I would go with separate operations and just use common data types, defined in the xsd whenever needed.

The other option is to not use minOccurs=0. This will make the xsd shorter and somewhat more flexible, but also more open to interpretation (which, when describing a service more bad than good). If you need to give the wsdl to someone in order to consume your service in the future this will require more description of the different use cases (create/update) in the documentation. The other approach is more straightforward and intuitive for developers.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a common structure for create and update.
When a data carrying element is declared in an XSD it should have the attrivute nilable set to true e.g.:

```
<xsd:element name="Result" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
```

This allows for the `xsi:nil` attribute to be applied to the element.

[1]

> ```
> <tag>Data</tag>
> <tag xsi:nil=”false”>Data</tag>
> <tag xsi:nil=””>Data</tag>
> ```

Tag is present and includes data. There may be an empty xsi:nil attribute or the attribute may not be present.

The target application needs to update the field with the specified data.

[2]

> ```
> <tag></tag>
> <tag xsi:nil=””></tag>
> <tag xsi:nil=”false”></tag>
> <tag/>
> <tag xsi:nil=""/>
> ```

Tag is present and is self closing or does not include data. There may be an empty xsi:nil attribute or the attribute may not be present.
 The target application needs to update the field to zero length data. E.g. an empty string.

Some applications may update the data to null.***

[3]

> ```
> <tag xsi:nil=”true”>Data</tag>
> <tag xsi:nil=”true”></tag>
> <tag xsi:nil=”true”/>
> ```

Tag has the xsi:nil attribute set to true. It may or may not contain data and it may or may not be self closing.
 The corresponding field should be updated to null.

[4]

> Tag is missing from the xml.

No update should occur on the corresponding field